# How to change the URL of window parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window

In my HTML page A, there is a button that opens up a popup window B using the `window.open` function. Now in that popup B, can JavaScript code change the location of A? Note: the JavaScript is in B.

I tried `parent.window.location = parent.window.location;` because I'm trying to refresh the parent, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refresh the parent window, try this:

```
window.parent.location.reload();
```

Or

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

Comment: i will try these new ones out

Comment: window.opener.location.reload(); worked, but since it's a reload, I get the popup about wanting to resend information (microsoft postback stuff), can I just change the link to the same link to do a refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.opener.location.reload(true);
```

The true parameter also use to do force reload. It will ignore cache.

```
window.opener.location.reload(false);
```

The false parameter use to do force reload from cache..

We can use reload function with out using parameter like,

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

Thanks..

Comment: what does the false do in the end?

Comment: From MDN: window.location.reload(forceget) - Reload the document from the current URL. forceget is a boolean, which, when it is true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)

Comment: @HJ05 yes that's right. By default the forceget value will be true.